# How to install android sdk components via chocolatey

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

I need help installing android-SDK components such as build tools, platform and others. I tried downloading it manually from android studio what I saw was tools other components are missing.

Comment: Have you tried this [link](https://chocolatey.org/packages/android-sdk)?

Comment: Thanks @A.A. it's been solved. I appreciate it.

Comment: Posting a formal answer to help people find it more quickly. @T.Samuel [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

To [install the Android SDK with chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/android-sdk), you can run the following command:

```
choco install android-sdk
```